# Build Lambda Expressions with Contains on NetCore

Tags: c#, expression

Good affertoon people.

I have a problem, when I tried build a lambda expression with Expression.Builder the code throw a error.

Say: "Static method requires null instance, non-static method requires non-null instance.".

I'm already successful with simple expressions like:

```
IQueryable<PersonTestModel> expected = data.Where(x => x.IsActive);


PersonTestModel expected = data.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id != 3);


IQueryable<PersonTestModel> expected = data.Where(x => x.FirstName.StartsWith("a", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));


IQueryable<PersonTestModel> expected = data.Where(x => x.Balance > averageBalance);
```

but, I can't build this expression

```
var dataFilter = new HashSet<int> { 2 };
IQueryable<PersonTestModel> data = await PersonFaker.GetFakeSimpleData(60);

//this is expression i will try
Expression<Func<PersonTestModel, bool>> func = x => dataFilter.Contains(x.UserId);
var expected = data.Where(func);
```

This is my code, for build commos expressions:

```
private static Expression GetExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameter, QueryFilter queryFilter)
        {
            MemberExpression member = Expression.Property(parameter, queryFilter.PropertyName);
            ConstantExpression constant = GetConstant(member.Type, queryFilter.Value);

            switch (queryFilter.Operator)
            {
                case Operator.Equals:
                    return Expression.Equal(member, constant);
                case Operator.NotEqual:
                    return Expression.NotEqual(member, constant);
                case Operator.Contains:
                case Operator.StartsWith:
                case Operator.EndsWith:
                    {
                        constant = GetConstant(member.Type, queryFilter.Value.ToUpper());
                        return Expression.Call(Expression.Call(member, "ToUpper", null), queryFilter.Operator.ToString(), null, constant);
                    }
                case Operator.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThan(member, constant);
                case Operator.GreaterOrEqualThan:
                    return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                case Operator.LessThan:
                    return Expression.LessThan(member, constant);
                case Operator.LessOrEqualThan:
                    return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(member, constant);
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"The type {queryFilter.Operator} not is a type selector valid.");
            }
        }
```

but with that expression I received a error message, this is the code

```
private static Expression GetComplexExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameter, QueryFilter queryFilter)
{
    MemberExpression member = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, queryFilter.PropertyName);

    MethodInfo method = typeof(HashSet<int>).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Single(x => x.Name == "Contains" && x.IsFinal && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
    var constant = Expression.Constant(queryFilter.Values);
    MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = Expression.Call(method, constant, member);

    return methodCallExpression;
}
```

I search on google, but the only result on my searchs is this code on stackoverflow:

[Build Lambda Expressions with Contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924505/build-lambda-expressions-with-contains)
Very thanks for you interesting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to try, I found an answer to my problem, the above code was close.

```
private static Expression GetComplexExpression<T>(ParameterExpression parameter, QueryFilter queryFilter)
{
    MemberExpression value = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, queryFilter.PropertyName);

    MethodInfo method = typeof(HashSet<string>)
        .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .Single(x => x.Name == "Contains" && x.IsFinal && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);

    ConstantExpression listContains = Expression.Constant(queryFilter.Values);

    MethodCallExpression body = Expression.Call(listContains, method, value);

    return body;
}
```

I only change the used method for this

```
public static MethodCallExpression Call(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, params Expression[] arguments);
```

I hope help other people with my answer.