# C# Building a generic IQueryable with abstract classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Hi I'm trying to build a generic `IQueryable` method using abstract clases which are implemented by other entities. This `IQueryable` is able to access resource permissions in order to filter the resources visible to the user.

Using these abstract entities then I can extend them in entities to have users permissions.

```cs
    public abstract class Resource<TEntity, TEntityPermission> 
        where TEntityPermission : ResourcePermission<TEntity>
    {
        public User Owner { get; set; }
        public string OwnerId { get; set; }
        public bool Public { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<TEntityPermission> Permissions { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ResourcePermission<TEntity>
    {
        public User User { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public TEntity Resource { get; set; }
        public string ResourceId { get; set; }
    }
```

For example, creating an entity Client using the resource and resource permission.

```cs
    public class Client : Resource<Client, ClientPermission>
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class ClientPermission : ResourcePermission<Client>
    {
    }
```

What I'm trying is to implement this `IQueryable` extension so not to have repeated `IQueryable` for each entity.

```cs
    public static class ResourceExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> FromUser<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string userId) 
            where T : Resource<T, ResourcePermission<T>>
            => query.Where(q => q.Public || 
                                q.OwnerId.Equals(userId) || 
                                q.Permissions.Any(pp => pp.UserId.Equals(userId)));
    }
```

And the error comes here using the `FromUser` method.

```cs
      await _context.Clients
          .FromUser(userId) <-- Error here
          .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

`Error: The type 'Client' must be convertible to 'Resource<Client,ResourcePermission<Client>>' in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic method 'IQueryable<T> FromUser<T>(this IQueryable<T>, string)'`

But `ClientPermission` extends from `ResourcePermission<Client>`. So what am I missing here?

**EDIT:** Modifiying the extension to accept the permission type is a solution, but still not what I would like to have.

```cs
public static IQueryable<T> FromUser<T, TP>(this IQueryable<T> query, string userId) 
            where T : Resource<T, TP>
            where TP : ResourcePermission<T>
            => query.Where(q => q.Public || 
                                q.OwnerId.Equals(userId) || 
                                q.Permissions.Any(pp => pp.UserId.Equals(userId)));
```

Then the in the query

```cs
      await _context.Clients
          .FromUser<Client, ClientPermission>(userId)
          .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Have similar problem and I solve it with  Generic Lamba Expression (Expression Tree)
This post may help you :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924505/build-lambda-expressions-with-contains

Comment: What happens if you explicitly specify the type arguments?

Comment: I manage it to work, but it does not convince me.

```c#
public static IQueryable<T> FromUser<T, TP>(this IQueryable<T> query, string userId) 
            where T : Resource<T, TP>
            where TP : ResourcePermission<T>
            => query.Where(q => q.Public || 
                                q.OwnerId.Equals(userId) || 
                                q.Permissions.Any(pp => pp.UserId.Equals(userId)));
```

As I have to put explicit the types using the method FromUser<T, TP>(userId)

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but look up covariance and contravariance. If not already, you're going to run into it very soon and it may cause you to have to redesign your entire approach.

Comment: Thanks will look into it.